# Matrix dimensions of the svd() output in R

Tags: r, svd

From the second paragraph here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

SVD of an m x n matrix M with m columns and n rows =
UDV* where

```
U is m x m 
D is m x n 
V is n x n
```

using some dummy data and R

```
M =data.frame(x = seq(1,100,1), y = seq(101,200,1), z =seq(301,400,1))
dim(M) # here m=3 and n = 100
D = diag(svd(M)$d) #  singular vectors
percentVariance2 = svd(M)$d^2/sum(svd(M)$d^2)
U = svd(M)$u # right singular vectors --eigenvectors
V = svd(M)$v # left singular vectors

dim(U) # 100x3
dim(D) # 3x3
dim(V) # 3x3
```

So when I run SVD in R on M which is m=3 and n =100 I get

```
U is n x m 
D is m x m 
V is m x m
```

Why are the dimensions different from the reference?

Notice the original data can still be obtained using U,D and V

```
recompose_M = U %*% D %*% t(V)
head(recompose_M)
head(M)
```

Comment: @GeoMatt22 OP has wrongly reported the R's output. `dim(U) # 3x100` is wrong, it is actually 100x3, as it should be.

Comment: (I edited to fix it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it does not make sense to find more singular values than the amount of rows or columns. Because of this the default in R only computes `min(n, p)` singular vectors where `n = nrow(x)` and `p = ncol(x)`.

If you really want to you can change this behavior by changing the parameters of `svd`:

```
M =data.frame(x = seq(1,100,1), y = seq(101,200,1), z =seq(301,400,1))
dim(M) # here m=3 and n = 100
uvd = svd(M, nu = 100, nv = 3) 
D = diag(uvd$d)
percentVariance2 = D^2/sum(D^2)
U = uvd$u # right singular vectors 
V = uvd$v # left singular vectors
```

But notice that only the first 3 components make sense.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 you do not use R, so Matlab or python?

Comment: @hxd1011 mainly Matlab, but starting to learn Python. So the matrix dimensions in the OP make sense to you? i.e. multiply U*D = [3 x 100]*[3 x 3]? Matlab would certainly give an error. Is it to do with something like C vs. Fortran array storage/indexing order?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 please check this question I asked: R is automatically fixing the matrix multiplicatio for you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025900/matrix-and-vector-multiplication-operation-in-r

Comment: Note that "it does not make sense to find more singular values than the [matrix rank]" is literally true. But there are **certainly** cases where it makes sense to find more singular *vectors*, which form a basis for the matrix's null space. (For example, in linear-equality constrained optimization. In practice QR decomposition would typically be used rather than full-on SVD, of course.)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 you are right, R will fix on vector but not matrix.

Comment: @hxd1011 No "fixing" here; OP simply reported wrong dimensions of the R output - see my comment to the OP.